# Flutter Pagination in the ListView.builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to integrate pagination in my flutter app and here is what I have done

```
class Tedd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeddState createState() => _TeddState();
}

class _TeddState extends State<Tedd> {
  NewsArticleService _articleService = NewsArticleService();
  List<NewsModel> _newsList = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  int currentPage = 1;
  bool hasReachedEnd = false;

  _getAllNews() async {
    if (hasReachedEnd) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var articles = await _articleService.getAllNews(page: currentPage);
    var result = json.decode(articles.body);
    result['data'].forEach((data) {
      var news = NewsModel();
      news.id = data["id"];
      news.articleTitle = data["name"];
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _newsList.add(news);
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    });

    if(result["meta"]['current_page'] == result["meta"]['last_page']){
      setState(() {
        hasReachedEnd = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        currentPage++;
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _getAllNews();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _newsList.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _newsList.length) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return Container(
              height: 150, child: Text(_newsList[index].articleTitle!));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And Here is my Repository class

```
class Repository {
  String _baseUrl = "pkbhai.com";
  String _subUrl =  "myprojects/kids-stories/api";

  httpGet(String api) async {
    return await http.get(Uri.https(_baseUrl, "$_subUrl/$api"));
  }
}
class NewsArticleService {
  Repository? _repository;
  NewsArticleService() {
    _repository = Repository();
  }
  getAllNews({int? page = 1}) async {
    return await _repository?.httpGet('all-stories?page=$page');
  }
}
```

I want to fetch more available data when I scroll more and more.

But I am not getting pagination data, where am I doing wrong please suggest to me,

here is my JSON data please take a look
https://pkbhai.com/myprojects/kids-stories/api/all-stories

Comment: Take a look at this package [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Comment: Actually, I can not pass the right parameters to this, that's why I posted my question here.